# Using AMPscript to attach a file

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

We are sending email templates from Service Cloud and using the Marketing Cloud API to send the emails.

Now we are trying to include AMPscript (AttachFile) in the HTML content of the email but when the email is sent, the AMPscript part is rendered literally. What should I do to render the AMPscript correctly? I am new to AMPscript.

Screenshots:
[image: Mail received with AMSCRIPT in the content]

[image: AMPScript included in HTML email]

HTMLContent that I am sending is shown .I put a log in my code to see what i am sending to SFMC:

```
<html>
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <title></title> 
 </head> 
 <body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; text-size-adjust: none; font-size: 16px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; height: auto; min-height: auto;">
  %%[ var @fileName, @fileAlias set @fileName = &quot;https://image.msg.com/lib/fe3c11717564047c751d73/m/1/ea9bc2a7-3110-42ab-9ea6-7c16b7bf66d2.pdf&quot; set @fileAlias = &quot;Support_V0.2.pdf&quot; ]%% 
  <br />contentMath (evaluated): %%=treatascontent(AttachFile('HTTP', @fileName,@fileAlias))=%% 
  <table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tb_properties border_style" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="100%"> 
   <tbody> 
    <tr> 
     <td align="center" valign="top"> 
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
       <tbody> 
        <tr> 
         <td class="content_padding" style=""> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
           <tbody> 
            <tr> 
             <td align="center" class="header" valign="top"> 
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
               <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                 <td align="left" valign="top"> 
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%"> 
                   <tbody> 
                    <tr> 
                     <td class="responsive-td" style="width: 100%;" valign="top"> 
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style="min-width: 100%;" width="100%"> 
                       <tbody> ..............................
 

 - code in sfdc to prepare the payload

    'to' => em.recipient,
                    'contactKey' => em.contactKey,
                    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object> {
                            'HTMLContent' => em.content,
                            'Subject' => em.subject
                    }   
            };
            recipients.add(recipient);
        }
        Map<String, Object> requestBody = new Map<String, Object>{
                'definitionKey' => sendDefinition,
                'recipients' => recipients
        };
        return requestBody
```

Comment: Hi @Adam Spriggs, If you could help me out here.This seems to me very much doable,my lack of Ampscript knowledge is what is limiting here.I just googled that treatascontent function could help but i am not sure how to use it in this context.

Comment: Are file attachments provisioned in your account?

Comment: I think I will need to check it? Could that be a reason that the ampscript is rendering as it is?

Comment: Last time I checked AttachFile didn't support https.  I'd also double-check your fileName in your browser to confirm it's accessible.

Comment: I'd put your AMPscript before everything else in the email -- not in the head section.

Comment: My file name is accessible(these docs are uploaded to marketing cloud only and i am getting their links through their properties.). I have also tested sending the payload with ampscript in the body section.thats what you mean when you say "before everything else"

Comment: @Adam Spriggs ,Even if i include below Ampscipt,it still renders as it is:```%%[ VAR @Name SET @Name = "Chetan" LOWERCASE(Name) ]%% %%[ VAR @text SET @text = "Hello, world!" Output(v(@text))]%%```

Comment: What kind of block are you using in Content Builder?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I am not using content builder.Its all in sfdc.The templates and the call to sfmc transactional api.we send the html content in the payload .and that is where i am trying to modify the email content(in sfdc).

Comment: Can you show us the payload you're using?

Comment: I have updated my question @ zuzannamj .it shows the html content that we send to SFMc and also the code how we prepare payload in SFDC.